# Get the JSON Object Node Count in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I am facing issue with getting the count of the JSON Object having particular value for the parameter Name

In the Below JSON I wanted to get counts having name : IN PROGRESS as 2. Can you please help me let me know what is going wrong here.

The name parameter is present under issues>fields>status

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oK1qyxmWnc44vHZ8vlW3?p=preview)

**JSON Data**

```
 {
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 257,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1579217",
      "fields": {
        "created": "2017-08-11T13:03:52.000+0000",
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "status": {
          "name": "IN PROGRESS",
          "id": "3"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1578077",
      "fields": {
        "created": "2017-08-10T13:14:53.000+0000",
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "status": {
          "name": "IN PROGRESS",
          "id": "10548"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1562078",
      "fields": {
        "created": "2017-07-27T03:42:24.000+0000",
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "status": {
          "name": "To Do",
          "id": "10548"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Angular JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar']);

app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", "$window",
  function($scope, $http, $window, $filter) {

    $scope.findTheValue = function() {

      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'issues.json'
      }).then(function(response) {

        $scope.selectedCount = $filter('filter')(response.issues, {
          name: 'IN PROGRESS'
        }).length;

        console.log($scope.selectedCount);

      })
    }

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your above code

First, the order of dependency injection is not correct.

```
app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$http","$filter", "$window",
  function($scope, $http, $filter, $window) {
```

Second, since you are using POST, you have to pass some data to the API call. Pass empty data `{}` to your `POST` or use `GET`

Third, you have to access the data property of your response like `response.data.issues`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", "$window",
    function($scope, $http, $filter, $window) {
        $scope.findTheValue = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'issues.json'
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.selectedCount = $filter('filter')(response.data.issues, function(
                    inputs) {
                    if (inputs.fields.status.name == 'IN PROGRESS') return inputs;
                });
                console.log($scope.selectedCount.length);
            })
        }
    }
]);
```

**Working Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZOEN3X7Nt1onNeaHMp0H?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

To get the `count`, you can simply `iterate` through the array and check how many times particular value is occuring. I have used `reduce` to get the count and return the sum when the value is `IN PROGRESS`.

```js
var data = {
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 257,
  "issues": [{
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1579217",
      "fields": {
        "created": "2017-08-11T13:03:52.000+0000",
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "status": {
          "name": "IN PROGRESS",
          "id": "3"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1578077",
      "fields": {
        "created": "2017-08-10T13:14:53.000+0000",
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "status": {
          "name": "IN PROGRESS",
          "id": "10548"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1562078",
      "fields": {
        "created": "2017-07-27T03:42:24.000+0000",
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "status": {
          "name": "To Do",
          "id": "10548"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

function getCount() {
  return data.issues.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(curr.fields.status.name === 'IN PROGRESS') {
      return acc + 1;
    }
    return acc;
  },0);
}

console.log(getCount());
```